# IEnumerable of object returns JSON, but IEnumerable of similar object does not

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two classes that are similar. I'm trying to see if I can simply use one. The first is in our DataModel assembly, and used in our DbContext.

```
public partial class type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice
{
    public int MotorCarrierFreightInvoiceId { get; set; } // MotorCarrierFreightInvoiceId (Primary key)
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; } // InvoiceId
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; } // BillDate

    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; } // TrackingNumber

    public decimal NetShipmentCharge { get; set; } // NetShipmentCharge

    public long InterchangeTransactionDetailId { get; set; } // InterchangeTransactionDetailId

    public long? BillToAddressId { get; set; } // BillToAddressId
    public long? ConsigneeAddressId { get; set; } // ConsigneeAddressId
    public long? ShipperAddressId { get; set; } // ShipperAddressId

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual interchange_TransactionDetail interchange_TransactionDetail { get; set; } // fk_Type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice_Interchange_TransactionDetail
    public virtual typeAny_Address typeAny_Address_BillToAddressId { get; set; } 
    public virtual typeAny_Address typeAny_Address_ConsigneeAddressId { get; set; } 
    public virtual typeAny_Address typeAny_Address_ShipperAddressId { get; set; } 

    public type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();
}
```

The second class should represent the same object.

```
public class Type210MotorCarrierFreightInvoice
{
    public int MotorCarrierFreightInvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime BillDate { get; set; }

    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal NetShipmentCharge { get; set; }
    public long InterchangeTransactionDetailId { get; set; }
    public Address BillToAddress { get; set; }
    public Address ConsigneeAddress { get; set; }
    public Address ShipperAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I'm working with a WebApi service that will expose the data via JSON. Basically what I'm trying is this:

```
[Route("api/Subscriber/Get210sNew/{transactionId}")]
[Route("api/Subscriber/Get210sNew/{transactionId}/{limit}")]
public IEnumerable<type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice> Get210sDOES_NOT_WORK(int transactionId, int limit = DefaultLimit)
{
    var key = new QueryAfterId(transactionId, limit);
    var dataService = new Type210DataService(_ediContext);
    return dataService
            .Get(key)
            .Select(x => x);
}

[Route("api/Subscriber/Get210s/{transactionId}")]
[Route("api/Subscriber/Get210s/{transactionId}/{limit}")]
public IEnumerable<type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice> Get210sWorks(int transactionId, int limit = DefaultLimit)
{
    var key = new QueryAfterId(transactionId, limit);
    var dataService = new Type210DataService(_ediContext);
    return dataService
            .Get(key)
            .Select(Map);
}
```

Here is the `Map` method:

```
private static Type210MotorCarrierFreightInvoice Map(
    type210_MotorCarrierFreightInvoice dbNotice)
{
    return new Type210MotorCarrierFreightInvoice
    {
        MotorCarrierFreightInvoiceId = dbNotice.MotorCarrierFreightInvoiceId,
        InvoiceId = dbNotice.InvoiceId,
        BillDate = dbNotice.BillDate,
        ShipDate = dbNotice.ShipDate,
        TrackingNumber = dbNotice.TrackingNumber,
        PurchaseOrderNumber = dbNotice.PurchaseOrderNumber,
        BillOfLading = dbNotice.BillOfLading,
        NetShipmentCharge = dbNotice.NetShipmentCharge,
        InterchangeTransactionDetailId = dbNotice.InterchangeTransactionDetailId,
        BillToAddress = Mapper.MapToAddress(dbNotice.typeAny_Address_BillToAddressId),
        ConsigneeAddress = Mapper.MapToAddress(dbNotice.typeAny_Address_ConsigneeAddressId),
        ShipperAddress = Mapper.MapToAddress(dbNotice.typeAny_Address_ShipperAddressId)
    };
}
```

Get210sWorks will return Json data to the browser. Get210sDOES_NOT_WORK does not. Both queries get the same number of records. But Get210sDOES_NOT_WORK shows no records in the browser window.

Why can't I return an IEnumerable of my DataModel class as Json?

Comment: WHen you say it doesn't work, what exactly happens? Do you get an exception? If so, what are the exception details?

Comment: Sorry, added comments at the end. One returns Json to the browser, one doesn't.

Comment: PS, Fiddler says I get a 500 Internal Server Error, but I see no error in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you not missing the mapping of address fields in the `DOES_NOT_WORK` one which might lead to a failure or an inner exception for casting? try wrapping around `try catch` block to see the inner exception if any